# Akka - Deprecation Compile Errors

Tags: java, ubuntu, akka

I've decided to tackle Akka... which was going great until compile time :-/ Running Ubuntu by the way.

What I've Done So Far:

1. Installed JRE and JDK 7
2. Downloaded/Extracted Akka
3. Downloaded and Setup Maven
4. Set up PATH variables etc

All following this tutorial [Tutorial](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.2/intro/getting-started-first-java.html)

When compiling, I'm getting the following errors

```
javac -cp lib/scala-library.jar:lib/akka/akka-actor_2.10-2.2.1.jar akka-tutorial-first-java/src/main/java/akka/tutorial/first/java/Pi.java -Xlint:deprecation
akka-tutorial-first-java/src/main/java/akka/tutorial/first/java/Pi.java:8: warning: [deprecation] UntypedActorFactory in akka.actor has been deprecated
import akka.actor.UntypedActorFactory;
                 ^
akka-tutorial-first-java/src/main/java/akka/tutorial/first/java/Pi.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
import akka.util.Duration;
                ^
  symbol:   class Duration
  location: package akka.util
akka-tutorial-first-java/src/main/java/akka/tutorial/first/java/Pi.java:56: error: cannot find symbol
    private final Duration duration;
                  ^
  symbol:   class Duration
  location: class PiApproximation
akka-tutorial-first-java/src/main/java/akka/tutorial/first/java/Pi.java:58: error: cannot find symbol
    public PiApproximation(double pi, Duration duration) {
                                      ^
  symbol:   class Duration
  location: class PiApproximation
akka-tutorial-first-java/src/main/java/akka/tutorial/first/java/Pi.java:67: error: cannot find symbol
    public Duration getDuration() {
           ^
  symbol:   class Duration
  location: class PiApproximation
akka-tutorial-first-java/src/main/java/akka/tutorial/first/java/Pi.java:112: warning: [deprecation] Props(Class<? extends Actor>) in Props has been deprecated
      workerRouter = this.getContext().actorOf(new Props(Worker.class).withRouter(new RoundRobinRouter(nrOfWorkers)),
                                               ^
akka-tutorial-first-java/src/main/java/akka/tutorial/first/java/Pi.java:127: error: cannot find symbol
          Duration duration = Duration.create(System.currentTimeMillis() - start, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
          ^
  symbol:   class Duration
  location: class Master
akka-tutorial-first-java/src/main/java/akka/tutorial/first/java/Pi.java:127: error: cannot find symbol
          Duration duration = Duration.create(System.currentTimeMillis() - start, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                              ^
  symbol:   variable Duration
  location: class Master
akka-tutorial-first-java/src/main/java/akka/tutorial/first/java/Pi.java:158: warning: [deprecation] Props(Class<? extends Actor>) in Props has been deprecated
    final ActorRef listener = system.actorOf(new Props(Listener.class), "listener");
                                             ^
akka-tutorial-first-java/src/main/java/akka/tutorial/first/java/Pi.java:161: warning: [deprecation] UntypedActorFactory in akka.actor has been deprecated
    ActorRef master = system.actorOf(new Props(new UntypedActorFactory() {
                                                   ^
akka-tutorial-first-java/src/main/java/akka/tutorial/first/java/Pi.java:161: warning: [deprecation] Props(UntypedActorFactory) in Props has been deprecated
    ActorRef master = system.actorOf(new Props(new UntypedActorFactory() {
                                     ^
akka-tutorial-first-java/src/main/java/akka/tutorial/first/java/Pi.java:168: error: method tell in class ActorRef cannot be applied to given types;
    master.tell(new Calculate());
          ^
  required: Object,ActorRef<br/>
  found: Calculate<br/>
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length<br/>
7 errors<br/>
5 warnings
```

I've literally copied ans pasted their final Pi.java file and tried to compile and i'm completely at a loss as how to proceed? :-(

Any ideas would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to get started with Akka is by using Typesafe’s [Activator](http://typesafe.com/platform/getstarted): there are several tutorials in there which show you how to do different things, starting from “Hello Akka” to using advanced Cluster features, you can see the full list [here](http://typesafe.com/activator/templates).

That said, your problems come from trying to run a tutorial from the 2.0.2 docs on Akka 2.2.1, which will not work.

Comment: DOH!! My bad... this is the only Tut I could find. Perhaps I should start with Activator first then :-/